# Google Maps constantly requesting location

Tags: google-maps, privacy, geolocation

I'm running LBP Privacy Guard, and every 30 minutes or so I get a warning that Google Maps is trying to request my location.

Why is this, and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Have you Latitude running?

Comment: It is installed, but I've never used it..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching off "location sharing"?

It is under "Privacy settings" in settings menu.  Read more [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142065)